# How to send a pid from one file to another?

Tags: c, pid

i have a client and a server program,but the problem is that i first run the ./server and than run the ./client with a pid that the server program creates,how can i do this automatically?
server.c

```
void my_handler(int signum){
    if (signum == SIGINT){
        printf("Received SIGINT!\n");
        printf("haiku_category: japanese\n");
    } 
    if (signum == SIGQUIT){
        printf("Received SIGQUIT!\n");
        printf("haiku_category: western\n");
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pid;
    pid=getpid();
    printf("PID: %d\n", pid);

    signal(SIGINT, my_handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT, my_handler);
    pause();
}
```

and client.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    srand(time(0));

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        int random_int = rand()%2;
        printf("random_int: %d\n",random_int);
        if(random_int==0)  kill(atol(argv[1]),SIGINT);
        else kill(atol(argv[1]),SIGQUIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about writing it to a file, and have the client read that file?

Comment: @ikegami solved my problems with file i/o thanks!

Comment: @TurqayUmudzade that supposes only one server and client run at the same time on the same machine, or both have to get in argument the pathname of that file and you use a different one each time